# Other's domains pointing to my site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

My problem is domains that belong to others pointing to my site. So in the google search results their domain is listed instead of mine (their domain name is totally different from what my site does so could chase away the customers). We informed the owners of these domains months ago but sadly no action taken from their part.

My site is built using asp.net mvc 4. If I use,
Context.Request.Url.Host to find these domains and display an error page, will it remove these domains from google natural list and display my site instead?

I am open to solutions with IIS, asp.net/globla.asax or anything else!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have asp.net on tags, I probably can provide some solution but via asp.net and use of global.asax, not via iis

Comment: @Aristos that would be great! solution with asp.net and global.asax is fine

Comment: If you just set up your site in IIS to use the [host headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx), it won't respond if the domain name doesn't match.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You have absolutely right on that, but I have also see that happens, other url domains and get my data, how this can be possible ? maybe mirror ? maybe dns tricks, maybe iframes ?

Comment: @Aristos - there's no technical solution to them scraping the content and re-hosting it. For iframes you can set the `X-Frame-Options` header.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Then maybe he has not set the host headers, have dedicate ip and place "*" to allow any name, and some other have just make some dns to show their site.

Answer (score 0):

You could return code [410 Gone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) from global

If you put this in Global.asax.cs and replace ourdomain.com with your domain you're laughing. Google should see the 410 and remove from its indexes.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (!Request.Url.Host.Contains("ourdomain.com"))
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 410;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

You could expand this more if you like to have a list of domains etc, but this is a good starting place.

Note:
Google should remove sites for a very very long time if 410 returned, but [best do some more research](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGB570GB570&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20bot%20410%20remove)